# How can i remove the button of my form when i go to the print preview

Tags: c#, mysql, printing

Hello guys goodevening to you... how can i remove the button 6 to my print preview ? i dont have any idea even when i false the visible of the button6 
[image: payslip print preview]
[image: RUNNING FORM]

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        bitmap = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        Graphics grp = panel.CreateGraphics();
        Size formSize = this.ClientSize;
        bitmap = new Bitmap(formSize.Width, formSize.Height, grp);
        grp = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        Point panelLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
        grp.CopyFromScreen(panelLocation.X, panelLocation.Y, 0, 0, formSize);
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();



    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

}
//CODE

Comment: Set the button viability = 0

Comment: where sir @Brad

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button6.Visible = false;//add here
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        Graphics grp = panel.CreateGraphics();
        Size formSize = this.ClientSize;
        bitmap = new Bitmap(formSize.Width, formSize.Height, grp);
        grp = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        Point panelLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
        grp.CopyFromScreen(panelLocation.X, panelLocation.Y, 0, 0, formSize);
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    }

    private void printPreviewDialog1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        button6.Visible = true;//this is to enable button after closing print screen 
    }
```

Comment: Please add some description

Comment: @Karthi M button6  is still on the print preview

Comment: he still exist on the print preview even when i false :(

Comment: Just add before capturing screen same like me.. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In order for the button to actually become invisible, you have to force the events to actually run.

In your button6_Click event handler you begin with the lines:

```
button6.Visible = false;
Application.DoEvents();
```

The DoEvents() method forces the events in the event queue to run. This is because you run on the UI thread. I would not recomend you move the copying operation to another thread, but another way would be to start an UI timer (found under Components in the tools menu) and have that timer timout at a few ms. You can then have the copying operation there. But the easiest solution is to simply add the Application.DoEvents() so that is my recommendation.